# How to retrieve the latest and second latest date for each ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, maxdate

My SQL database looks like this

```
ID DATE 
1  2017-01-01
1  2017-01-03
1  2017-01-05
2  2017-01-06 
2  2017-01-07
2  2017-01-08
2  2017-01-11
3  2017-01-11
```

How can I retrieve the Max(DATE) and second latest date for each ID as in below.

```
 ID MAXDATE     SECONDMAXDATE        
 1  2017-01-05  2017-01-03  
 2  2017-01-11  2017-01-08
 3  2017-01-11  2017-01-11 (or 'NONE')
```

PS: when there is only 1 record, SECONDMAXDATE can display either the MAXDATE or a STRING (eg. NONE)

Comment: tag the database being used.

Comment: which database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the simplest method is the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` "hack":

```
select id, max(date),
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(date order by date desc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as second_date
from t
group by id;
```

Note:  This returns the second date as a string rather than a date.  You can convert it back to a date if you like.

Also, `group_concat()` has a default maximum length of 1,024 bytes.  This is sufficient for most purposes (a hundred dates or so).  If you have more dates per id, then this mechanism is probably not the best mechanism.

Comment: I was slowly preparing an answer then Gordon arrived again with the best solution

Comment: Thank you Gordon. Yes I do have thousands of dates.. If there a way I could merge 2 tables? one with MAXDATE, and the other with SECONDDATE? If so how could I get the SECONDDATE for each ID?

Comment: Also, how would I be able to convert it back to a date in the same query?

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria . . . Just use `date()` around the expression.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.id
     , x.date
  FROM
     ( SELECT id
            , date
            , CASE WHEN @prev=id THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=id prev 
         FROM my_table
            , ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
            , date DESC
     ) x
 WHERE i <= 2;
```